# OnBindViewHolder is triggered only once

Tags: android, kotlin

**What is Happening:** Even though there are two elements in `val list: ArrayList<StudentModel>` collection as seen in image below and I have explicitly given size `2` in `getItemCount()`. Only  once `onBindViewHolder` is triggered

[image]

**AdapterCode**

```
class ListAdapter(private val list: ArrayList<StudentModel>,val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
        return MovieViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.frag_disp_group_blocks, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Timber.i("$list.size")
        return 2
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie = list[position]
        Timber.i("$movie")
        Timber.i("$movie.get(position)")

        holder?.tvAnimalType?.text = ""
    }

}

class MovieViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
    val tvAnimalType = view.list_title
}
```

Comment: why don't you use list.size for itemCount?

Comment: Even though I use `list.size` still it is triggered only once .... that's why I have posted array size pic

Comment: How are you confirming it is called only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a mistake from my side .... I had given the matchParent params so it was triggering once. wrapContent did solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

passing a context from activity/fragment is not necessary unless they serve the purpose of their usage. Use context from the onCreateViewHolder parameter parent.

```
return MovieViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.frag_disp_group_blocks, parent, false))
```

Comment: Thank you pointing me out ... I have upvoted for this information :)